# CodeGlance Plugin wont change the appearance of the editor in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, plugins, editor, appearance

I'm trying to change the appearance of my editor in Android Studio. In **File => Settings => Plugins => Browse Repositories** I installed a Plugin called **CodeGlance**. After the restart of the editor, the editor should have looked different but I have still the same appearance. Does someone know how to fix that problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pressing `ctrl + shift + g` toggles the CodeGlance plug-in

Comment: You saved my day, sir. I couldn't figured it out. It didn't occurred me that the plugin will have such setting. So probably I just pressed this combination by a mistake. Do you know  whether this hotkey can be disabled/changed?

Comment: glad to have helped! sorry, I'm not sure if you can change this.